# getc() does not return carrige return '\r' character

Tags: c, stdio

I have a text file "hello.txt" with some sample text. When I open the file in a hex editor, I can see \r\n characters for the newline. But when I read the file in a C program with getc() the \r somehow vanishes and I only see the \n character.

I tried to search online and on stackoverflow but with no luck.

hello.txt

```
Sample
File
```

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("hello.txt", "r");

    int character = 0;

    while( (character = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%.2X ", character);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
53 61 6D 70 6C 65 0A 46 69 6C 65
```

File as seen from hex editor:

```
53 61 6D 70 6C 65 0D 0A 46 69 6C 65
```

As can be seen, the 0D0A is output as only 0A when using the getc() function.

Why does getc() avoid the '\r' character ? How can I get it to return the EXACT data in a given file i.e. without any conversions for the \r\n to \n ?

Comment: Try opening it in binary mode, `"rb"` to get the `'\r'`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Windows you must open the file in *binary* mode:

```
fp = fopen("hello.txt", "rb");
```

The default, *text* mode, translates the DOS/Windows line ending `\r\n` into a single character.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at getc() all this while. I didn't even suspect the read mode would affect this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the file open in text mode `fp = fopen("hello.txt", "r");`,  the `0x0D` character if predecing `0x0A` character will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Try `fp = fopen("hello.txt", "rb");` - with the `'b'` in the open mode, the file is opened in 'test mode' which will translate/normalize line endings (depending on the platform) to simply `\n`.